# Dynamically changing text

Tags: text, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a text component called `txtUsername` and I can't for the life of me change it to show "Ryan."

This is what I've tried:

[Linked the text component to the variable `user` like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlZmg.png)

My JS script:

```
var username = "Ryan";
var user : UI.Text;


// set username text
function SetUsernameText() {
user = GetComponent(UI.Text);
user.text = username;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use GetComponent(UI.Text) since you already attached that gameobject in the inspector, try this:

```
var username = "Ryan";
var user : UI.Text;


// set username text
function SetUsernameText() {
user.text = username;
}
```